# Is there a performance difference between removing filters from entire table vs columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

DateTbl dimension: date, year, month, Week

Customer dimension: id, Cust name, department

Sales: date, custid, SalesAmt, PurchaseAmt, Profit

Relation between DateTbl and sales is on date column. Relation between customer and sales is on custid column.

I have a matrix visual with rows as Cust name, department. Columns are year, month, week. Values is SalesAmt.

I want to create a new measure showing SalesAmt Last year. Note: without using time intelligence.

So I wrote:

```
LY SalesAmt = 
VAR YR = MAX(DATETBL('YEAR')
VAR WK = MAX(DATETBL('WEEK')
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(SALES['SALESAMT']), REMOVEFILTERS(DATETBL), DATETBL['YEAR']=YR-1, DATETBL['WEEK']=WK)
```

Instead of REMOVEFILTERS I can also use ALL. But since ALL returns entire table it will be a less performant solution.

The above DAX seems to work but I want to ask whether it is necessary to remove filters from entire date table or can I remove filters from individual columns to make the DAX more efficient/performant?